# Django update from 3.2 -> 4.0 and DRF Paths

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-4.0

I wanted to try and upgrade my django app that runs just fine on django 3.2.6 to the next release, but even in testing I came across the deprecated `url` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/).

So I replaced the last lines in the `urls.py`:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'products', views.ProductViewSet, basename = "products")

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    url('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

but on a site that has the url `http://127.0.0.1:8003/productspage/` I now get the error message: `The current path, productspage/api/products/, didn’t match any of these.`

The path for the api in the ajax calls with django 3.26 was working:

```
async function doAjax ( ) {
    let result = await $.ajax({url: "api/products/"});
}
```

so I totally see why this would not work - but how (and where?) do I fix it?

I thought about handing an absolute path (like `${window.location.hostname}/api/products/`) to ajax, or providing a [basename](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) for the template? Can I fix it in Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#url) was alias to [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/#re-path) and not to [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/#path) so in your case

```
...
re_path('api/', include(router.urls)),
...
```

Comment: but shouldn't it be possible to use `path` too? I know about `re_path`. Technically you are correct though.

Comment: No as DRF router implementation still uses regex strings notation for routes, and not the new syntax.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!